# How to block an IP, if it is making many http/apache/mysql requests in a second?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, ddos, security

If some one tried force burst attack on my website, how can i block their IP address?

I mean, I want to block an IP if I am getting many http/Apache/SQL requests per second from it. How can i prevent those force burst attacks?

**Linux Server**

thank in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're looking for [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/).